# How to generate non-source files (e.g. json) in C#/ .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I've started using Source Generator in .NET 5  to generate some custom serialization code. This works beautifully for my use case.
However I'd also like to create a  custom schema for said serializer in the form of a JSON file. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way to output said generated file using Source Generators.
Is this possible at all? Or perhaps I should use some other method of generation?

Comment: What do you want to *happen* to this non-source file? is it to be interpreted as an embedded resource? you can't make it appear in the *regular* source tree, if that is your intention; I *believe* additional output types is a "next wave" feature, meaning: in the *initial* cut they wanted to ship the minimal surface to achieve some well understood problems, with code generation for the compiler being the main aim

Comment: I want to copy it to the output folder, then finally include it into the nuget package as a json

Comment: If I were you I'd take a look at using [T4 templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019) this was a way to generate code (and other files) before source generators.

Comment: I think that's a really interesting question, but I believe the answer is "no, you can't do that currently" - however, Chris Sienkiewicz (chsienki on GitHub, chiser99 on Twitter) would know for sure - to be honest, this is probably a question for the Roslyn team (and in particular, Chris)

Comment: Right now I'm looking at using MSBuild properties to get pass in the output path, reading that from the generator, and writing the file manually. I know it's horrible, but it kind of works.

Answer (score 5):

This is a scenario we're actively looking at, but don't have the current bandwidth to implement. We did some early work to see how it would work for analyzers here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/49046

Logically that work would flow to generators as well, but as noted above, right now the answer is 'no, it's not possible'.

We have a tracking issue at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/57608. Feel free to thumbs up, or add your particular scenario to it which helps when it comes to prioritization.